# Cordova camera plugin: nullpointer exception

Tags: android, cordova, nullpointerexception, cordova-plugins

We are using cordova-plugin-camera (version 2.2) in our Hybrid app. Our App crashes every now and then and this is due to a NullPointerException when Camera is invoked. We have tested on Android 4.4.4 and multiple difference devices running this OS and the result is the same.  This error seems to have been reported at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9477 and claims this has been fixed in Cordova v2.2 but we are facing the same error.

Here is our camera launch code:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(uri) {
        console.log(uri);
        document.getElementById("loadImage").src = uri;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }, { 
        quality : 100,
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    });
```

Anybody else facing same/similar error and any known solutions?

```
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066): Process: com.intelleza.wombix.care, PID: 32066
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.care/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.care.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=34, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.care/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.care.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2825)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5028)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=34, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.care/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.care.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3373)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    ... 12 more
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.processResultFromCamera(CameraLauncher.java:420)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.onActivityResult(CameraLauncher.java:753)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterfaceImpl.onActivityResult(CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:120)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onActivityResult(CordovaActivity.java:353)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5433)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3369)
05-12 16:43:55.111: E/AndroidRuntime(32066):    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Did you removed and re-added your platform after updating to the latest plugin version?

Comment: Yes, it was done but the problem still persists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)